# Azure AD and user management for application that allows user registration

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-appservice

I am creating an application deployed to azure app service that allows users to register to create accounts.  Users can also provide profile information such as phone, address, username, etc.  Can this type of application be integrated with Azure AD such that users are created in Azure AD with the the custom profile properties they input when they register?  Or does this have to be managed outside Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MS Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview) in tandem with more than [7 programming languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview#supported-languages) to manage Azure AD resources such as [users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0), [groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groups-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) and more.

Properties such as phone, address, username are standard properties of the [user resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Also, you can store additional information using [4 different type of extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview#custom-property-options-in-microsoft-graph).

Finally, if feasible, you can store more information externally and relate it to each user using its object identifier (user id property).